# Regex pattern match exclude

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I would like to match if an email address has invalid TLD.

I have the following regex:

```
/^[A-Z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Z0-9.-]+\.[A-Z]{2,4}$/i
```

It will match test@test.couk

The value 'couk' is not a valid TLD, how can I edit the above to exclude couk at the end of the email address.

Comment: Here is the list of valid tld: http://data.iana.org/TLD/tlds-alpha-by-domain.txt

Comment: http://davidcel.is/blog/2012/09/06/stop-validating-email-addresses-with-regex/

Answer (score 0):

With regex you can validate only the string's pattern. It has 2-4 letters, ok - it's valid !

To check if TLD is really valid you have to compare it with some TLD database that you have to specify. No other way, sorry !

Answer (score 0):

You could try a negative look-ahead: `(?!couk)`

[`^[A-Z\d._%+-]+@[A-Z\d.-]+\.((?!couk)[A-Z]{2,4})$`](http://tinyurl.com/qjxzeeh)